# Technical requirements for new (mid-2016) subscription model in Apple App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, subscription

Apple revamped the subscription model for the App Store as of mid-2016, making it available to more kinds of apps and expanding its feature set.

What are the technical requirements for developing an app offering such subscriptions as their business model?

- Does it require iOS 10 or later for the user?
- Does it require Xcode 8 or later for the developer?
  (Xcode 8 supports developing apps only for iOS 8 and later, dropping support for iOS 7, 6, and lower.)
- Has the nature or content of the in-app-purchase Receipt changed?

I have read doc such as these, but cannot find any thing about system/technical requirements:

- [Working with Subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html)
- [Auto Renewable Subscriptions FAQ](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/In-App%20Purchases_Auto-Renewable%20Subscriptions)
- [Offering Subscriptions](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/)

Comment: I think Xcode 8 still lets you support older versions of iOS. Just set the Deployment Target to whatever you want.

Comment: As long as you have put your products into subscription groups then the auto-renew upgrade/downgrade process is handled by the store and the subscription management system.  I don't believe there are any requirements on the device or app.  If a user purchases a subscription that is a "downgrade" then you will get a revised receipt with that product after the current subscription term expires (i.e. at renewal date).  If the user purchases an "upgrade" then you receive an updated receipt with the new product immediately

Comment: The upgrade or downgrade isn't handled directly in your app, however.  If the user purchases a subscription that is in the same group as an active subscription then they are shown an alert that prompts them to open the iTunes subscription management system

Comment: @Paulw11 actually upgrade/downgrade can be handled by your app. You would just make those items available for "purchase" and your app with server side support would need to manage that part properly. For example if your Group had product ids A, B, and C and the customer has purchased B, you can offer them A and C. You would have them "purchase" it and it would be treated as an upgrade/downgrade/crossgrade. I had a conversation with Apple and asked them if it was possible to do within the app and that was what they told me.

Comment: That is what I would hope too, but unfortunately because you can't access the "manage" system from a Sandbox user I can't confirm this.  I know that in my current testing, purchasing an upgrade/downgrade simply results in StoreKit prompting the user to "manage" their subscriptions and the purchase doesn't complete

Comment: @maddy No, Xcode 8 does *not* let you set deployment target to earlier than iOS 8. I've seen for myself, even on an existing project converted from Xcode 7 to Xcode 8, you get a compiler warning that iOS 8 is minimum target, and insists you change the deployment target. The popup-menu of choices show only iOS 8 and later.

Comment: hi @Paulw11, you said "If a user purchases a subscription that is a "downgrade" then you will get a revised receipt". What exactly does this revised receipt look like? (meaning does it include the new plan immediately or is it added only after the next renewal date?). Second question, is this the behavior you see in production?

Comment: Only after the next renewal date.   An upgrade takes effect immediately but a downgrade takes effect after the end of the current period.